# Kotlin Generic class using inheritance

Tags: kotlin, generics, inheritance

I have a BaseClass and several ChildClasses. I BaseClass has a doSomething() function, which I have to override. I **cannot** change BaseClass or any ChildClass.

```
class BaseClass {
   fun doSomething() {}
}

class ChildClass1 : BaseClass {}
class ChildClass2 : BaseClass {}
```

The overridden doSomething() function of the ChildClass have to do the same thing. So I could do this:

```
class MyChildClass1 : ChildClass1 {
   override doSomething() {
      // some tasks
   }
}
class MyChildClass2 : ChildClass2 {
   override doSomething() {
      // same tasks as in ChildClass1
   }
}
```

Obviously, I dont want boilerplate code. I thought about Kotlin Generics where I define on class and depending on which ChildClass I pass in, it overrides the doSomething() function.
The context is actually a little bit more complex, so I cant just pass a lambda or something like that.
Here some **pseudo code**, what I try to achieve:

```
class GenericClass : <T: BaseClass> {
   override doSomething() {
      // tasks ...
   }
}

var genericChildClass1 = GenericClass<ChildClass1>()
```

Is this somehow possible in Kotlin?

Thanks!

Comment: How can you do anything if you can’t change the classes?

Comment: The classes are from a library. I pass those objects into a asyn API call of this library. The doSomething() function is a callback. I will set a future there.

Comment: Do the tasks you want in your doSomething() function need private access to the internals of the classes you can't change?  If not, you could put the common code in a utility/extension function.

Comment: @gidds They do not need access to the members of BaseClass or ChildClass. I also wrote already a utility class, which I can pack inside MyChildClass1, MyChildClass 2 and so on. However, I still would have to extend all ChildClasses oder override doSomething() with the same tasks of my utility class.

Comment: There won't be any way around this without _some_ boilerplate.  You will have to have all your child classes override to forward to the same method.

Comment: @LouisWasserman So there are no solution using Generics?

Comment: There is no clear way in which generics will help here.